# problema con los elementos de una lista

Tags: python, lista

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que quite ciertos elementos de un grupo de listas si pasa cierta condición, y que los duplique si pasa cierta otra.
Pero tengo el siguiente problema: **cuando el programa se encuentra en la iteración 50 de 100, marca IndexError y se cierra**.

Aquí está el fragmento del código en el que tengo el problema:

```
    nnl_len = len(neuralNetworkList) # longitud de lista de objetos (siempre 100)
    fitl_copy = fitness # lista de floats (siempre de longitud 100)
    best_fitness_reproduced = 0 

    if worst_fitness < 0 and first_iteration == 0: # supongo que esto se
        worst_fitness = 0                          # puede ignorar


        for i in range(nnl_len):
            print(i)
            if fitl_copy[i] < best_fitness: # LINEA EXACTA DEL ERROR <------------------
                print("I DIED WITH A FITNESS OF ",fitness[i], ", BEING THE LIMIT ",best_fitness)
                neuralNetworkList.pop(i)    
                x.pop(i)
                y.pop(i)
                fitness.pop(i)
                colors.pop(i)
            elif fitl_copy[i] == best_fitness and best_fitness_reproduced:
                print("I DIED BECAUSE A TOP FITNESS CREATURE ALREADY REPRODUCED ",fitness[i])
                neuralNetworkList.pop(i)    
                x.pop(i)
                y.pop(i)
                fitness.pop(i)
                colors.pop(i)               
            else:           
                best_fitness_reproduced = 1
                for j in range(99): # plus the mother is 100
                    print("I SURVIVED WITH A FITNESS OF ",fitness[i], ", BEING THE LIMIT ",best_fitness)                    
                    neuralNetworkList.append(neuralNetworkList[i])
                    if random.randint(1,3) == 1:
                        neuralNetworkList[i].mutate(i)
                    x.append(width)
                    y.append(height)
                    fitness.append(0)

                    newcolor = []

                    for h in range(3):
                        newcolor.append(round( colors[i][h]*random.choice((0.9, 1.1)) ))

                    colors.append(newcolor)     
            #except IndexError:
            #   pass
            #   print("I NEITHER DIED NOR REPRODUCED BECAUSE OF AN INDEX ERROR")

        nnl_len = len(neuralNetworkList)

        for i in range(nnl_len):
            x[i] = width
            y[i] = height
            fitness[i] = 0

        print("population after reproduction:", len(neuralNetworkList))
```

este es el traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ezequiel\Desktop\Archivos pavos\Sublime Text 3\pruebas_phyton.pyw", line 4921, in <module>
    if fitl_copy[i] < best_fitness: # fitness[i] <= worst_fitness*4
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**gracias por anticipado**

Comment: Hay muchos lugares donde `IndexError` puede ocurrir. ¿Puedes publicar el seguimiento que obtienes de la excepción?

Comment: @SebastianSalazar perdón, a que te refieres con un seguimiento de la excepción?

Comment: Me refiero al Traceback de tu excepción

Comment: @SebastianSalazar 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ezequiel\Desktop\Archivos pavos\Sublime Text 3\pruebas_phyton.pyw", line 4921, in <module>
    if fitl_copy[i] < best_fitness: # fitness[i] <= worst_fitness*4
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Ezequiel edita tu pregunta y alli añade tu traceback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cuando el programa está en la iteración 50 de 100, marca IndexError y
>   se cierra.

Esa es la pista; El problema ocurre a la mitad del proceso. Esta es una señal de tratar de [eliminar de una lista mientras itera sobre ella](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating); cada vez a través del ciclo, elimina un elemento, por lo que después de 50 veces que tiene `i == 50` y solo 50 elementos aún en la lista, el índice está fuera de los límites.

¿Por qué pasó esto? Bien...

```
fitl_copy = fitness # lista de floats
```

Esto no hace una copia de `fitness`; hace otro nombre para `fitness`.

En consecuencia, estas dos líneas ...

```
if fitl_copy[i] < best_fitness:
    # ...
    fitness.pop(i)
```

opera en la misma lista; y bum.

Creo que primero deberías intentar repensar tu algoritmo. Supongo que realmente no es necesario querer hacer estallar todo de las listas en absoluto. Creo que será mucho más fácil si:

- Reescribe para producir una nueva lista con todas las criaturas de la nueva generación, comenzando desde cero (lista vacía).
- Deja la lista de criaturas anterior sola mientras haces esto, y luego reemplázala con la lista nueva al final

También puede beneficiarse al usar algún tipo de datos estructurados para sus criaturas, en lugar de tener listas paralelas con todos sus atributos; y también mediante el uso de listas de comprensiones y generadores en lugar de for-loops.

Comment: En realidad, al leer el código nuevamente, parece que quieres que se reproduzca exactamente una criatura, la primera en la lista que está vinculada a la mejor condición física. Entonces, realmente no desea procesar todos los elementos de la lista de forma iterativa; quieres encontrar la criatura que califica y reproducirla.

Comment: muchas gracias! no sabía que lista1 = lista2 le daba un nuevo nombre a una lista. lista1 = list(lista2) serviría? la razón por la que tengo listas paralelas en vez de todo junto es que estoy programando una función para crear redes neuronales, y para no tener que editar su código cada vez que la utilice en proyectos distintos, decidí almacenar información no relacionada con la función en listas apartes.

Comment: Sí, llamar `list()` a una lista existente hace una copia (superficial). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list en que verá esto en el código anterior. Pero si el objetivo es hacer una copia , entonces en el nuevo código (Python 3.3 en adelante) solo debe usar el `.copy()` método de la lista.